# What if recipient of the package can't pay the duty and tax on a shipment

Tags: customs-and-immigration, local-customs, import-taxes

I sent a package to my friend in nigeria I never sent put of the us and they can't pay duty and tax I shipped by ups I even called ups to see if I could pay it but since it was shipped at local store and sent through their account I can't will the package be returned to me

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about travel.

Comment: This question is clearly not about price-shopping for specific goods, the majority of the vote-to-close votes are voting to close for the wrong reason...

Comment: I vote for reopening too, the question as written has nothing to do to price shopping. What real customs do when you don't have enough money to pay duty - they hold your package for some time (and you're charged for storage). If not claimed within certain time frame, it becomes the property of State and auctioned off (or thrashed if little value). This seem however to be a typical Nigerian scam - the OP should expect a request to "send the duty amount" via a Western Union.

Comment: Agree with @George, this sounds like a typical scam. Have you met this friend in person? 'Sent through their account'  I guess means you don't have access to the tracking information and signature if it was received (or indeed even shipped or possibly redirected). Also if it was sent on a genuine business account it would normally be delivered and the fees billed.

Comment: While this question may be closed for the wrong reason, it needs some editing to its body. I’m having a hard time deducing what it’s asking (but that could be the 4 a.m. effect).

Comment: @GeorgeY. Sure, it has nothing to do with price-shopping. But it also has nothing whatsoever to do with travel, so it's completely off-topic here. It's also not even a question. It's a shame when questions get closed for the wrong reason but it was absolutely correct to close it.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: we do have a handful of customs-related questions here, and we answer some. If we remove "on shipment" from the title, would that be better? The answer is essentially the same whether you ship it or bring it with you (the custom form even asks about "unaccompanied baggage").

Comment: @GeorgeY. We answer _travel-related_ questions about customs. This is a "question" about sending a parcel internationally. It has nothing whatsoever to do with travel. The asker was not travelling; they were not shipping some of their baggage unaccompanied: they were just sending a parcel. And I put quotes around "question" because the post isn't even a question!